# Null pointer exception trying to write to SD card in android

Tags: java, android

This is the code I have in my onCreate() method in the starting activity for my app

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);


    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.img);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);

//you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "test.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    try {
        fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fo.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is meant to load an image into a bitmap and then make a file on the SD card named "test.jpg" with the image inside, however this is not what is happening.

Instead, I get a null pointer exception on the line

```
 fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
```

The error message is:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.daniel.firstapp/com.example.daniel.firstapp.startup}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.FileOutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
```

Comment: I am checking now, but it shouldn't be? ... Comment above deleted, it asked if I had checked bm was not null

Comment: `bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);` seems to be passing `null` to your `bytes`

Comment: Why would it be doing this? img is in the Drawable folder

Comment: Try to debug your `onCreate` method step by step. I belive your `bytes` will be null after this line: `bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);`

Comment: @dazito *" I belive your bytes will be null after this line"* ... this is not what is Exception is saying.

Comment: @Tom, you are right. My bad.

Comment: *"but a new error arises"* If you have a new error (I guess you mean _exception_), then create a new question for it. If the posted answer doesn't solve your (now fixed) problem, then feel free to create an own answer and explain there what you did to solve the problem.

Comment: First off, there is no use if the following code, `try { f.createNewFile(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` and wrap all the exception code in single try catch

Answer (score 0):

First: Why so many `try/catch`?

Second: Your `fo` variable is `null`.

Probably because the file could not be created.

Make sure you have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and replace it with a `FileOutputStream` instead.

NB: try/catch blocks omitted for clarity.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.jpg");
// 'this' in the following line refers to an instance of your Activity, if you're doing your output from a fragment or helper class, get a reference to your activity.
FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(f.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.img);
//PNG doesn't compress because it's lossless
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

fos.flush();
fos.close();
bm.recycle();
```

also make sure you have the appropriate write external storage permission set in your manifest.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Getting the same exception or a new one?

Comment: The same one unfortunatly

Comment: what line in the new code is throwing the NullPointer?

Comment: fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

Comment: Also, there is no file in the SD card when I look at it from the emulator

Answer (score 0):

starting from android 4.4, normal applications are not allowed to access secondary external storage devices, i.e. sd card, except in their package-specific directories, even if you have requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

> The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission must only grant write access to
>   the primary external storage on a device. Apps must not be allowed to
>   write to secondary external storage devices, except in their
>   package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions.
>   Restricting writes in this way ensures the system can clean up files
>   when applications are uninstalled.

https://source.android.com/devices/storage/

Actually your application has thrown exception in the line below, because of the restriction.

```
FileOutputStream fo = null;
try {
    fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```